# Custom Block (Slick Slider) Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, template, custom-block

Trying to add a Slick(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider to homepage.  It looks simple enough, but I have been banging my head against the wall for the last 2 days.

Here's what I have done:

1) Created `home_slider.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/pkg/default/template` to create a custom block that displays the banners and load the slider js. `alert()` to let me know at least it's loading.  I have tested the code on jsfiddle to know it works.

home_slider.phtml

```
<div class="home_slider">
    <div><a href="111"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/web-banner_2015_1.png')?>" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="222"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/web-banner_2015_2.png')?>" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="333"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/banner3.jpg')?>" /></a></div>
</div>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('slick/slick.min.js')?>"></script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var slider = $(".home_slider");
    slider.on('init', function(){ 
        alert('fire in the hole!');
    });
    slider.slick({
        initialSlide: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
</script>
```

2) Modified `local.xml` in `app/design/frontend/pkg/default/layout` to insert the slider block on homepage right at the top.

local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <remove name="top.container" />  <!-- does not remove header-language-background completely, done with css -->
            <remove name="welcome" />                   
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>  <!-- removes My Cart and Checkout from Account header nav -->      
        </reference>    
    </default>  
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="home_slider" template="home_slider.phtml" before="-">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>  
</layout>
```

The banners load, but Slick is not working (alert didn't fire) and I can't figure out why.  Do I need to create a custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this may be it is `jquery` conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
    var slider = jQuery(".home_slider");
    slider.on('init', function(){ 
        alert('fire in the hole!');
    });
    slider.slick({
        initialSlide: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That did it!  Off to bang my head on the wall one last time so I would remember to do that in the future.  Thank you.